# jQuery $(window).scrollLeft() Does Not Work in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: jquery

If I add this piece of code to a simple HTML page created in Visual Studio then it works. (I get values greater than 0 for windowLeft and windowTop.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).click(function(e) {
        var windowLeft = $(window).scrollLeft();
        var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();

        var message = "Window Left: " + windowLeft + "\n" +
                      "Window Top: " + windowTop;
        alert(message);
    });
});
```

If I add the exact code to a Script Editor Web Part on a web part page in SharePoint 2013, then scrollLeft() and scrollTop() always returns 0 even when I scrolled all the way to the right and bottom of the page.

Tried in IE11 and Chrome, and the same jQuery library is referenced by both environments. I've tested over a few hours but still can figure out why...

I hope someone can help me solve this puzzle. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint team embedded many JavaScript files in masterpage and they do many thing after `$(document).ready()`. You code is overridden by these JavaScript file by Microsoft.  There are some options available to hook custom code after PageLoad.

- SP.SOD.execute
- SP.SOD.executeFunc
- ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded
- SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded
- LoadSodByKey

**Execute after specific JavaScript file**,  Check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff409592(v=office.14).aspx)

`SP.SOD.executeFunc("SP.js", "SP.core.js", function() {
function init() {
         //your code goes here...
  }
  init();
});`

**Load on the end.**

`function runAtTheEnd(){
    // your code
}
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("runAtTheEnd");`

**Delay until load**
`function runAfterSpJs(){
    //your code
}
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(runAfterSpJs, "sp.js")`

Comment: Thanks Asim. I'll try the SP.SOD methods. I've seen the use of these methods before, and even I used some of them myself, but I've not understand them 100% due to lack of documentation. For example: SP.SOD.executeFunc(key, functionName, fn), where the second argument should be a function name, but in your example it looks like a file name instead, and I think your example is correct.